# ARIMA-GARCH with different parameters depending on the package

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, garch

I'm trying to forecast the CAC40, I get my ARIMA(4, 1 ,5) (with two non-significative parameters) model using the differents information criterion and correlograms. After testing the residuals I see that I need to add some GARCH effects, so I go for a GARCH(1, 1) and the residuals are fixed.

The problem is here, I want to predict it so  I use :

```
garch11 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                             mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(4, 5), include.mean = TRUE), 
                             distribution.model = "norm")
garchfit  <- ugarchfit(spec = garch11, data = lcac.ret, solver = "hybrid")
garchfit
```

I get totally different results and parameters. And it's not the best model since if I try the same code with, let's say, ARIMA(3, 1, 3) I get better results (more significative parameters, and lower AIC).

So I don't know what to do since there is no reason I should switch back to an ARIMA(3, 1 ,3) after the previous analyzes, and is this normal ? Why does it differs so much ?

And when I try with :

```
model=garchFit(~arma(4,5)+garch(1,1), data=lcac.ret, trace=F, cond.dist ='std')
```

I get again different results, how to explain this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your title question, your specifications are not the same: in `ugarchspec` you use a normal distribution for the standardized innovations (`distribution.model = "norm"`), while in `garchFit` you use a Student distribution (`cond.dist = 'std'`). No wonder the estimated coefficients are not the same.

For the remaining questions, I suggest posting them one by one rather than all in the same thread.

Comment: Ok, thank  you ! a very avoidable mistake. Wouldn't it be a bit *spammy* since they are quite close ?

Comment: @quezac, well, the ones that are close can stay together, but I think a couple distinct ones can be identified. You would probably not even need to ask them as there are some similar threads with answers already.